# What exactly does the d3 clipAngle method do?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am absolutely confused on what the clipAngle method in d3 does. I've poked in the wiki and in the library its self but am not able to put it in plain vanilla English.

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Geo-Projections#clipAngle

I see that my orthographic projection gets sliced in half if the clip angle is set to 90.

If set to 180 I see the front and the back of the sphere

Zero I se nothing

So basically I can imagine this as a plane slicing the sphere?

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine a pin that's anchored in the center of the sphere pointing straight at you, it's now at 0 degrees, and this doesn't render anything.  Change the angle of this pin by moving the end pointing at you up.  At 90° the pin is pointing straight up and it renders everything between 0° and 90°.  Rotate it a bit further and it starts to render the back half of the sphere.

For reference, here's one clipped at 107° so that it renders a bit of the backside and appears to "wrap" around the inner globe:

[image]